# missing nameserver in /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

Tags: ubuntu

Hi I have two virtual machines with ubuntu. One created couple months ago and it contain in file:

```
/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

two entries more

```
nameserver 10.192.192.22
nameserver 10.192.129.78
```

In new machine this two entries are missing and I can not ping computer in my network (only works for internet servers). I always get:

```
Temporary failure in name resolution
```

When I add this two nameservers everything works. Is there any option to add this lines and keep after reboot?

Answer (score 1):

NetworkManager is overwriting resolv.conf on reboot. In ubuntu you need to modify the dns settings through networkmanager -> ipv4 settings... then it will stick.